# Set endpoint for Soap UI in groovy script

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui

I need to add a new endpoint from groovy script to the testcase request in soapUI. Here I used rest project, my code is as follows:

```
def end= testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("dd").getHttpRequest().setEndpoint("http://cd-diudara:8280/services/linkedinFollowCompanyPage?wsdl")
```

This is getting me `null` in the "end" variable. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: This problem may have been solved on [soapUI form](http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=16436)

Answer (score 3):

Your code work as expected, if you open your testStep after groovy script execution, on the endpoint bar you will see your new endpoint. However `setEndpoint(endpoint)` method doesn't return nothing, this is the reason why you have a `null` in the "end" variable.

If you want to get the endpoint you can invoke `getEndpoint()`:

```
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("dd").getHttpRequest().setEndpoint("http://cd-diudara:8280/services/linkedinFollowCompanyPage?wsdl");
def end = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("dd").getHttpRequest().getEndpoint();
log.info end;
```